# Fetching CUDA texture problems

Tags: c++, cuda, textures

I am having trouble fetching a texture of floats. The texture is defined as follows:

```
texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> cornerTexture;
```

The binding and parameter settings are:

```
cornerTexture.addressMode[0]    = cudaAddressModeClamp;
cornerTexture.addressMode[1]    = cudaAddressModeClamp;
cornerTexture.filterMode        = cudaFilterModePoint;
cornerTexture.normalized        = false;
cudaChannelFormatDesc cornerDescription = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();


cudaBindTexture2D(0, &cornerTexture, cornerImage->imageData_device, &cornerDescription, cornerImage->width, cornerImage->height, cornerImage->widthStep);
```

`height` and `width` are the sizes of the two dimensions in terms of numbers of elements. `widthStep` is in terms of number of bytes. In-kernel access occurs as follows:

```
thisValue = tex2D(cornerTexture, thisPixel.x, thisPixel.y);
printf("thisPixel.x: %i thisPixel.y: %i thisValue: %f\n", thisPixel.x, thisPixel.y, thisValue);
```

`thisValue` should always be a non-negative float. `printf()` is giving me strange, useless values that are different from what the linear memory actually stores. I have tried offsetting the access with a `0.5f` on both coordinates, but it gives me the same wrong results.

Any ideas?

**Update** There seems to be a hidden alignment requirement. From what I can deduce, the pitch passed to the `cudaBindTexture` function needs to be a multiple of 32 bytes. For example, the following gives incorrect results

```
cudaBindTexture2D(0, &debugTexture, deviceFloats, &debugDescription, 10, 32, 40)
```

when fetching the texture, but the following (the same array with its width and height switched) works well:

```
cudaBindTexture2D(0, &debugTexture, deviceFloats, &debugDescription, 32, 10, 128)
```

I'm not sure whether I'm missing something or there really is a constraint on the pitch.

**Update 2:** I have filed a bug report with Nvidia. Those who are interested can view it in their developer zone, but I will post the reply back here.

Comment: what happens if you use the `%f` placeholder in that printf rather than %i (which is only meant for integral types)

Comment: Crap, you are right. Stupidest mistake ever...

Comment: Actually, the problem is still there. It is still giving me incorrect values.

Comment: Is the input pointer (cornerImage->imageData_device) aligned ? If it is allocated by cudaMalloc, it almost certainly is. If you are not sure, you can do cudaBindTexture2D(&offset,...) where offset is size_t; If offset is not 0, you will have to incorporate that when referencing the texture. Unfortunately, the cuda documentation is not entirely clear about how you can do that for 2D textures.

Comment: Where's the kernel that is being executed on this texture?

Comment: Yes it's cudaMalloced, so the offset as I see it should be 0... Ther kernel is 50 lines long so I didn't paste it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Nvidia reply to bug report:*

"The problem here is that the memory bound to the 2D texture does not have the proper alignment restrictions. Both the base offset of the texture memory, and the pitch, have certain HW dependant alignment restrictions. However, currently in the CUDA API, we only expose the base offset restriction as a device property, and not the pitch restriction.

The pitch restriction will be addressed in a future CUDA release. Meanwhile, it's recommended that apps use `cudaMallocPitch()` when allocating pitched memory, so that the driver takes care of satisfying all restrictions."

Answer (score 3):

There is definitely a constraint on the pitch, and unfortunately there is no device properties query to ask CUDA what it is.

But if you allocate the memory with `cudaMallocPitch()` and use the pitch passed back, that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the structure associated to the texture using the `cudaGetTextureReference` function?

From version 3.2 of the NVIDIA C Programming Guide (page 32, last paragraph):

> The format specified when binding a texture to a texture reference must match the parameters specified when declaring the texture reference; otherwise, the results of texture fetches **are undefined**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the high-level API; i.e. passing `cornerDescription` as a parameter to `cudaBindTexture2D()`, which removes a few lines of code and makes `cudaGetTextureReference()` redundant.

Comment: I've been reading that more people have encountered this problem of 32 bits alignment but no clues about an official answer. It's supposed the memory is aligned, right? How do you malloc the memory? Can you get the value of the offset (first paramenter) when calling cudaBindTexture2D() ?.

Comment: Have you consider use CUDA arrays for textures ?

Regards!