# CUDA Texture2D problems

Tags: cuda

I'm having trouble fetching from a 2D Texture

```
texture<float2, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;
// ...
assert(cudaMallocPitch(&imgcov2_device, &pitch, sizeof(ComplexFloat)*x*y*z, N*N) == cudaSuccess);
cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float2>();
tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
tex.normalized = false;
assert(cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, tex, imgcov2_device, channelDesc, x*y*z, N*N, x*y*z*N*N*sizeof(ComplexFloat)) == cudaSuccess);
// ...
tmp = ComplexFloatAdd(tmp, ComplexFloatMul(y[j + i*N], tex2D(tex, blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y + j*N))); //fetch
```

I am sure that the last 2 arguments to tex2D are in the range `[0,x*y*z-1]` and `[0,N*N-1]`. It was suggested in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778133/fetching-cuda-texture-problems) to use pitched memory, but I've had no luck. Any ideas? The fishy part is that it doesn't fail when x*y*z = 90000, N*N = 32^2 but not when N*N = 8^2. `ComplexFloat` is typedef-ed as `float2`. Only the fetch fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding the pitch linear memory to 2D texture, always use the pitch returned by `cudaMallocPitch` as the last argument of `cudaBindTexture2D`

In your case, you would do this:

```
cudaBindTexture2D(NULL, tex, imgcov2_device, channelDesc, x*y*z, N*N, pitch);
```